# How to handle 2 Header in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to handle 2 different header in my application:

- Menu
- A simple Bar with title

Firstly I’m thinking by using the local storage to save the menu I want to showUp (`localStorage.setItem('menu', 'default’);`) So when I’m in a component who don’t need the menu but just the simple bar I just resetting the localStorage like this : `localStorage.setItem('menu', ‘bar’);`

But this idea (I know it's not the best) didn’t re-render my header.  
What should I do to handle this case ?

In my render I have something like this :

```
render() {
        let menu = localStorage.getItem('menu');
        return (
            <header>
                {menu === 'bar' ? <TopBar/> : <MenuBar/>}
            </header>
        )
    }
```

Comment: why don`t using your header where your routes are locating?

Comment: @Samamone can you please check my answer? If you have any questions or feedback, please feel to write.

Comment: @JordanEnev Hey, sorry I moved on to something else this week, I'll be back to you next week. I think I'll try second suggestion, which I think is the most appropriate for my case. I will share my code when it works, otherwise I'll tell you.. But I think you put me on the right track :)

Answer (score 2):

Your Header isn't rerendered, because its props / state aren't changed. You're changing only the `localStorage` and this won't rerender your component.

I can suggest to you two approaches:

**1. Depending on which route you are, just use the proper Header:**

```
// Home.js
const Home = props => <>
  <MenuBar />
  // The rest components of your page
</>


// Inside.js
const Inside = props => <>
  <TopBar />
  // The rest components of your page
</>
```

**2. If you have a `<PageLayout />` component, you can use a prop for conditionally render the Header:**

*`<PageLayout />` is such a component, where we can reuse the page layout components composition. Every page has a header, body, footer. Instead of duplicating the same components structure in all the pages, it will be better to abstract the layout structure in `<PageLayout />`*.

```
const PageLayout = ({ header === 'default', children }) => <>
 <header>
   { header === 'bar' ? <TopBar /> : <MenuBar /> }
 </header>
 <body>
   {children}
 </body>
 <Footer />
</>

// Home.js - Here will use the `default` Header
const Home = props => <PageLayout>
  // The rest components of your page
</PageLayout

// Inside.js - Here we will use <TopBar /> 
const Inside = props => <PageLayout header='bar'>
  // The rest components of your page
</PageLayout
```